# Setting up SQL HA getting cannot find path error when running Enable-SqlAlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server

I have run a `new-cluster` successfully and now I am at the stage where I needs to run the following command but getting this error. I tried the troubleshooting and researched on google but not able to figured this one out. I have `sqlserver` module installed and `get-psDrive` shows `SQLSERVVER`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enable-SqlAlwaysOn -Path "SQLSERVER:\sql\computer\mssqlserver"
Enable-SqlAlwaysOn : Cannot find path 'SQLSERVER:\sql\computer\mssqlserver' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-SqlAlwaysOn -Path "SQLSERVER:\sql\computer\mssqlserver"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\sql\computer\mssqlserver:String) [Enable-SqlAlwaysOn], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.Hadr.EnableSqlHADRServiceCommand
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

```
PS C:\Users\test> cd SQLSERVER:\Sql\computer
PS SQLSERVER:\Sql\computer> dir

Instance Name
-------------
DEFAULT


PS C:\Users\test> Enable-SqlAlwaysOn -Path "SQLSERVER:\Sql\computer\default"

Enable AlwaysOn
To complete this action, we must restart the SQL Server service for server instance 'computer'. Do you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

it looks like I can run Enable-SqlAlwaysOn with default but not default name mssqlserver name..

Comment: That is correct. It is slightly unintuitive, but DEFAULT is the correct instance name which is replaced in many places under the covers by MSSQLSERVER.

Looks like you have it sorted now

Answer (score 2):

it looks like I can run Enable-SqlAlwaysOn with default but not default name mssqlserver name..

```
PS C:\Users\test> cd SQLSERVER:\Sql\computer
PS SQLSERVER:\Sql\computer> dir

Instance Name
-------------
DEFAULT


PS C:\Users\test> Enable-SqlAlwaysOn -Path "SQLSERVER:\Sql\computer\default"

Enable AlwaysOn
To complete this action, we must restart the SQL Server service for server instance 'computer'. Do you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```